# Windows installation error for postgresql. Error in make command

Tags: c, postgresql, ssl, locale, postgresql-9.5

I am new to postgresql. I want to install postgresql through source code in windows. I am using MinGW and msys for installation. Configure command is working fine with me. When i execute make command I am getting errors. Would any one please help me to rectify these errors.

```
[gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -O2 -I../../../../src/include -I./src/include/port/win32 -DEXEC_BACKEND  -I/home/roopteja.itha/openssl/include -I/home/roopteja.itha/uuid "-I../../../../src/include/port/win32" -DBUILDING_DLL  -c -o spgtextproc.o spgtextproc.c
In file included from ../../../../src/include/c.h:101:0,
                 from ../../../../src/include/postgres.h:47,
                 from spgtextproc.c:40:
../../../../src/include/pg_config_os.h:333:18: error: unknown type name '_locale_t'
 #define locale_t _locale_t
                  ^
../../../../src/include/utils/pg_locale.h:69:9: note: in expansion of macro 'locale_t'
 typedef locale_t pg_locale_t;
         ^~~~~~~~
make[4]: *** [spgtextproc.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/roopteja.itha/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend/access/spgist'
make[3]: *** [spgist-recursive] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/roopteja.itha/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend/access'
make[2]: *** [access-recursive] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/roopteja.itha/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend'
make[1]: *** [all-backend-recurse] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/roopteja.itha/postgresql-9.5.10/src'
make: *** [all-src-recurse] Error 2]
```

I am not able resolve this issue. Would anyone suggest necessary implementations.

Comment: It sounds like Configure is off a bit. How did you configure Postgres before building?

Answer (score 0):

The 'locale_t' type is defined in xlocale.h. The pg_locale.h has a condition before including xlocale.h One of the conditions might not be satisfied, so your xlocale.h is not included yet. Something like this.

```
#ifndef _PG_LOCALE_
#define _PG_LOCALE_

#if defined(LOCALE_T_IN_XLOCALE) || defined(WCSTOMBS_L_IN_XLOCALE)
#include <xlocale.h>
#endif
#ifdef USE_ICU
#include <unicode/ucol.h>
#endif
```